# SQL JOIN tables and and sum columns with the same PK

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables:

Players

| Name | DoB | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ben | 01/01/1999 | 1 |
| Tom | 02/01/1999 | 1 |
| Sam | 03/01/1999 | 1 |
| Sam | 03/01/1999 | 2 |

Ranking

| Ranking | Points |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 |

I want to join the tables and add the total points for each player then output this table.

Output

| Name | DoB | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ben | 01/01/1999 | 100 |
| Tom | 02/01/1999 | 100 |
| Sam | 03/01/1999 | 150 |

I am using this statement currently:

```
SELECT Matches.Name, 
       Matches.DoB, 
       Matches.Rankin, 
       SUM(Ranking.Points)
FROM Matches, Ranking
WHERE Matches.Ranking = Ranking.Ranking
GROUP BY Matches.Name
```

However I am getting this error when I run the code:

```
SELECT Matches.Name, Matches.Ranking, SUM(Ranking.Points)
FROM Matches, Ranking WHERE Matches.Ranking = Ranking.Ranking GROUP BY
Matches.Name LIMIT 0, 1000  Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT
list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
'ad.Matches.Ranking' which is not functionally dependent on columns in
GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
sql_mode=only_full_group_by 0.00044 sec
```

New to SQL so any help with this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Should be `GROUP BY Matches.Name, Matches.Ranking`?

Comment: The system is telling you what's wrong :). You need to include all non aggregated columns in your group by: `GROUP BY Matches.Name, Matches.DoB, Matches.Ranking`

Comment: Thank you! Is it okay if you explain what a 'non aggregated' column is?

Comment: yes: aggregations are functions like SUM, MAX, MIN, etc. So your aggregated column is SUM(Ranking.Points) in this case, and the other columns are 'nonaggregated'.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes so much sense now!!!! Thank you so much @VvdL, you're a star!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add all of your field in Select to the group by

```
SELECT Matches.Name, 
       Matches.DoB, 
       Matches.Rankin, 
       SUM(Ranking.Points)
FROM Matches, Ranking
WHERE Matches.Ranking = Ranking.Ranking
GROUP BY Matches.Name, Matches.DoB, Matches.Rankin
```